# Is there a way to change volume of <audio> in real time?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'd like to adjust the volume of an autoplaying, looping mp3 track based on the user's scroll position. I don't see any way to adjust the volume of the track playing, however. Is there a way to use JS, perhaps, to change the audio's volume?

I've looked through the tag's attributes, but the closest I could find was 'muted.' Do I need to use something like the Web Audio API instead?

Comment: You can adjust the volume in JS using the `volume` property of the `audio` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [`HTMLMediaElement.volume`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume). `HTMLAudioElement` (the interface for `<audio>`) inherits from `HTMLMediaElement`.

```
// Fade in the audio over the first 500 pixels of the document.
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  document.querySelector("audio").volume = window.scrollY / 500;
});
```